# VBScript Read Text file for multiple indexes and output to a new index

Tags: text, vbscript, find

I’m looking for a vbscript that can read each line of an input file, locate a particular value or set of values, and output those values (sorted Ascending) into a new lin. The file is an index file for a batch of documents being pushed up into an EDM system.

The values are those with the C1 tag, there can be between 0 values (do nothing) and a max of 5 values. I need to output the multiple values for this tag into a new C17 tag with a dash in-between them.

Incoming File Example:

```
[REPORT]
[BREAKDOC]
[Y:TIF]
[C1:222334444]
[C1:333445555]
[C1:444556666]
[ENDBREAK]
C:\PATH\TO\BATCH\IMAGES\IMG00001.TIF
[BREAKDOC]
[Y:TIF]
[C1:999887777]
[C1:888776666]
[C1:777665555]
[C1:666554444]
[C1:555443333]
[ENDBREAK]
C:\PATH\TO\BATCH\IMAGES\IMG00002.TIF
[BREAKDOC]
[Y:TIF]
[C1:123121234]
[ENDBREAK]
C:\PATH\TO\BATCH\IMAGES\IMG00003.TIF
```

Output File Example:

```
[REPORT]
[BREAKDOC]
[Y:TIF]
[C1:222334444]
[C1:333445555]
[C1:444556666]
[C17:222334444-333445555-444556666]
[ENDBREAK]
C:\PATH\TO\BATCH\IMAGES\IMG00001.TIF
[BREAKDOC]
[Y:TIF]
[C1:999887777]
[C1:888776666]
[C1:777665555]
[C1:666554444]
[C1:555443333]
[C17:555443333-666554444-777665555-888776666-999887777]
[ENDBREAK]
C:\PATH\TO\BATCH\IMAGES\IMG00002.TIF
[BREAKDOC]
[Y:TIF]
[C1:123121234]
[C17:123121234]
[ENDBREAK]
C:\PATH\TO\BATCH\IMAGES\IMG00003.TIF
```

This whole thing is part of a Batch Manager application, which can call a vbscript and run it on this file. When our vendor set up the system, they setup a few of these vbscripts, and I’ve one of these so as to provide a reference for setting up this particular script. I’m sure it’s pretty easy, I just don’t know the particular expression you'd need to put together in the last section of the script.

```
' Service variables for the operation of VBScriptLauncher
Dim   fso, Fichier_AAD, Fichier_CFG, Fichier_OUT
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2

Set fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If (WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("AAD")) Then
  Fichier_AAD = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("AAD")
End If

If (WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("CFG")) Then
  Fichier_CFG = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("CFG")
End If

If (WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("OUTFILE")) Then
  Fichier_OUT = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("OUTFILE")
End If

Set lecture = fso.OpenTextFile(Fichier_AAD,ForReading)
Set ecriture = fso.CreateTextFile(Fichier_OUT,ForWriting)

Do until lecture.AtEndOfStream

    '**************************
    '* reading from in file   *
    '**************************
    SLine = lecture.ReadLine

    'So long as the index C1 are not found, the category is rewritten in the output file
    pos = InStr(SLine,"[C1:")
    if pos = 0 then
        ecriture.WriteLine (sLine )
    else

        'The index C1 is found, it is rewritten in the AAD output file and then exploited
        ecriture.WriteLine (sLine)          

        sLine = UCase(sLine)
        taille=len(sLine)
        mois=mid(sLine,8,2)
        annee=mid(sLine,11,4)

        sLine = "[C18:" & mois & "]"
        ecriture.WriteLine (sLine)

        if right(annee,1)="]" then
        sLine = "[C19:" & annee 
        ecriture.WriteLine (sLine)
        else
        sLine = "[C19:" & annee & "]"
        ecriture.WriteLine (sLine)
        end if
    end if

Loop
```

Any questions or additional info needed, just ask and I will do my best to deliver.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Start with a simple/trival test script that reads your input sample, writes
all lines to an output file, and checks the output against your desired result:

```
  Dim sIn   : sIn       = "..\data\in00.txt"
  Dim sOut  : sOut      = "..\data\out00.txt"
  Dim sExp  : sExp      = "..\data\exp00.txt"
  Dim tsIn  : Set tsIn  = goFS.OpenTextFile(sIn)
  Dim tsOut : Set tsOut = goFS.CreateTextFile(sOut, True)
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     Dim sLine : sLine = tsIn.ReadLine
     tsOut.WriteLine sLine
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
  tsOut.Close
  If readAllFromFile(sOut) = readAllFromFile(sExp) Then
     WScript.Echo "Success"
  Else
     WScript.Echo "Failure"
  End If
```

Of course it fails. How to improve the Do .. Loop? The file names from the C1
lines/records have to be collected and before each [ENDBREAK] the C17 record
(sorted file names) must be written. Easy sorting in VBScript means System.Collections.ArrayList; easy parsing can be done with Mid(), i.e. positional access. Put that in code:

```
  Dim sIn    : sIn        = "..\data\in00.txt"
  Dim sOut   : sOut       = "..\data\out00.txt"
  Dim sExp   : sExp       = "..\data\exp00.txt"
  Dim tsIn   : Set tsIn   = goFS.OpenTextFile(sIn)
  Dim tsOut  : Set tsOut  = goFS.CreateTextFile(sOut, True)
  Dim alData : Set alData = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     Dim sLine : sLine = tsIn.ReadLine
     If "[ENDBREAK]" = sLine Then
        alData.Sort
        tsOut.WriteLine "[C17:" & Join(alData.ToArray(), "-") & "]"
        alData.Clear
     Else
        If "[C1:" = Left(sLine, 4) Then
           alData.Add Mid(sLine, 5, Len(sLine) - 5)
        End If
     End If
     tsOut.WriteLine sLine
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
  tsOut.Close
  If readAllFromFile(sOut) = readAllFromFile(sExp) Then
     WScript.Echo "Success"
  Else
     WScript.Echo "Failure"
  End If
```

Output for your sample:

```
Success
```

If you can't use an ArrayList or need more elaborate parsing, just say so.